# phpmyadmin login page doesn't show up

Tags: phpmyadmin

In http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ , I have set password 1234 for root user. And in confic.inc.php I have also changed it to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '1234';

When I go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/, it directly takes me to the phpmyadmin page without asking the username and password. Why it's not asking me the username and password? And if it doesn't ask then what's the point of setting a password?

Comment: it exists 2 logins, one for phpmyadmin and one for mysql. see which passsword you need for mysql with the mysql client, and use that in phpmyadmin config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the section of the manual that addresses authentication methods (https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-authentication-modes), or at least the short section about setting the auth_type (https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_auth_type). It can explain much more clearly than I can here.

Basically, you're using auth_type config, in which the configuration file (`config.inc.php`) has the username and password hardcoded and explicitly does not ask you to log in. If you wish to be prompted when logging in, you should use auth_type cookie (or http, if you insist, but I feel cookie is superior).

Some people are on a local or private network, or development setting, and don't want to have to log in constantly; 'config' is helpful for them but doesn't sound like what you want. Changing the auth_type in your `config.inc.php` will give you the solution you're after.